# Pandas how to separate same row with duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, by using pandas.concat with axis=1 I got the following dataframe:

|  | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

But I need the data to be displayed like the folowing example:

|  | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

Is there a way to either transform the first dataframe I talked about in the second one, or get the second one directly with another command other than concat?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `axis=0`

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should just use df.append() function not, pd.concat().
here is a brief example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[3,4]])
df.append(df2)
```